# Does webpack 4 dedupe npm packages that have, in turn, already been bundled by webpack?

Tags: npm, webpack, webpack-4

I have seen other similar questions. The questions I have seen were asked before the release of Webpack 4, did not ask specifically about npm, and were not definitively answered.

Let's say I use webpack to bundle a package that includes dependencies, and I don't want to categorize these dependencies as webpack externals and npm peer dependencies. I then publish this package to npm.

Someone downloads my package and uses it as part of a project. That project already includes one of my package's dependencies. Let's say this project is, in turn, bundled by webpack.

1.) Will webpack recognize and dedupe the duplicate dependencies when the project is bundled?

2.) If not, and if I don't use webpack to bundle my npm package, would it allow webpack to dedupe the duplicate dependencies when the project is bundled?

3.) What are best practices along these lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are already distributing a file that is bundled by webpack with all the dependencies, you don't need to declare dependencies nor peerDependencies.

> 1.) Will webpack recognize and dedupe the duplicate dependencies when the project is bundled?

Yes

> 3.) What are best practices along these lines?

Publish bundle with externals and peer dependencies and let the bundle happen on the user side.

Comment: So, for 3.) best practices, if I bundle with webpack, all dependencies should be external/peer dependencies? What if I have 5 uncommon dependencies? Every time someone uses my package they’ll have to download all 5, just to avoid duplication? That seems strange.

Comment: your uncommon dependencies are going to be downloaded when people install your package. Then webpack will do a better job on the other side. Publishing already bundled dependencies is not bad at all. That is up to you actually.

Comment: Thanks for your help! So you’re saying - if I bundle, it will dedupe. If I don’t bundle, with external/peer dependencies, it will automatically install the other dependencies when the user downloads my npm package? Or, the user will need to download the peer dependencies manually?

Comment: If you bundle or not bundle, webpack will dedupe anyways. The most used strategy is not to bundle and let the consumer of your application bundle it. That does not mean you can't bundle that, it is up to you. You can bundle if you want to ensure that it is going to work anywhere, despite anything

Comment: When you add as dependencies, when someone writes `npm install yourpackage`, it installs all the dependencies on the dependencies object on your package.json. When you put on peerDependencies, the user has to have those dependencies installed, they are not going to be installed automatically.

Comment: Got it. I see what you’re saying. Thank you!